# JAR file doesn't recognize update of a file that I'm reading in JAR

Tags: java, netbeans, jar, inputstream

I'm using Netbeans and in my program I'm reading a file. When I run the program it reads the file correctly. When I build the program the JAR also works correctly. But when I change the file that I am reading from, in my build dir, my JAR doesn't update accordingly. Why is that so? Is there a solution for this?

The code below shows how am I reading the file in my program. Thanks in advance.

```
InputStream in = NewJFrame.class.getResourceAsStream("/holidays.txt"); 
BufferedReader readHolidays = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
String line;
line = readHolidays.readLine();

while(line != null) {
    //read into hashmaps
    //...
    line = readHolidays.readLine();
}
readHolidays.close();
```

Comment: I am guessing that you did not close the opened file properly, but better to answer if you share more code

Comment: This is how i open file: InputStream in = NewJFrame.class.getResourceAsStream("/holidays.txt"); 
        BufferedReader readHolidays = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));  And then i just close bufferedReader... I execute this function in constructor. Function reads file and updates the HashMaps in which I've got information about holidays..

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, i got it ;) If anyone else needs this: Basically every time i run the program i find the file path to the jar file and from there i read text document.

```
File jarFile = new File(this.getClass().getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation().toURI()); 

FileInputStream is = new FileInputStream(jarFile.getParent().toString() + "/file.txt"); BufferedReader readFile= new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
```